# PHP Imagick timing out during execution while annotating image

Tags: php, imagick, annotate

I'm running into an unusual issue here. I'm simply trying to annotate an image with ImageMagick on PHP (installed via PECL), and the script times out. I've been able to narrow it down to where I annotate the image due to the fact that PHP tells me it times out at line 13 (code below):

```
<?
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImage("static/image.jpg");

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setStrokeColor("white");
$draw->setFillColor("black");

$draw->setStrokeWidth(2);
$draw->setFontSize(36);

//$draw->setFont("static/fonts/Impact.ttf");
$imagick->annotateimage($draw, 40, 40, 0, "Lorem Ipsum!");

header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $imagick;
?>
```

At this point in time I've just copied and pasted code from a tutorial. I did have my own code but it didn't work, so I decided to copy just to see whether I'd done something wrong. Lo and behold, this doesn't work either. If I remove both of the two lines ($draw->setFont) and the annotateImage it outputs the image just fine. For some reason I can not annotate correctly.

I can verify that it does not work if I use 'Arial' as the font instead of the copy of Impact.ttf that I have.

To clarify: I'm on OS X, using XAMPP.

Comment: Can you see what the process is doing while it's taking so long?  For example, on Linux you could run `strace -p [process id]` while it's running.

Comment: That's a good idea, actually. If a similar command exists on OS X (I should have a look), I'll check it out.

Comment: OK, so it seems to hang here: `read(0x1A, "\0", 0x1)   = -1 Err#35` before being killed.

Comment: Can you annotate a blank image as in the example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.annotateimage.php)?  If so, then try with your JPG but without the stroke color, width, font size settings -- just use the defaults.  Try to narrow down what it is that makes this operation break.

Comment: No, I'm unable to do anything that seems to pertain to loading a font or annotating an image. And yet, as soon as I remove both the `setFont()` method call and the call to `annotateImage()` the code executes.

Comment: This is most likely to be something weird about your system. Can you try running exec("convert static/image.jpg -fill black -stroke white -annotate '"Lorem Ipsum!"' testoutput.jpg"); which should do almost exactly the same thing, except directly with ImageMagick rather than going through the Imagick library.

Comment: btw error 35 is "EDEADLK     35  /* Resource deadlock would occur */" - I don't know what would cause that, but it sounds unusual.

Comment: I'm not getting any output from running exec. I've supplied an array and dumped the variable and its output is empty.

Comment: @Coldstream It shouldn't give any output - it runs silently. But does it generate the image okay or not?

Comment: It does not generate the image correctly. Running from the command line took about one minute and produced a garbled file.

Comment: So, by uninstalling both ImageMagick and imagick and then reinstalling them, the issue seems fixed. What I really wanted to know was what could have been causing the issue - it seems to have come out of the blue. However, thank you all for your assistance.